# SharePoint Visual Studio deploy does not overwrite display templates on update

Tags: sharepoint-2013, display-templates

- I have a VS SharePoint project where I placed some files in, in this case display templates.
- The elements.xml has ReplaceContent tot TRUE on each FILE entry
- The "Deployment Conflict Resolution" properties setting is "PROMPT"
- I see everything gets overwritten

It update everything. But sometimes a display template will revert to an old version. On first start I check the pages and see the old javascript code in there. (so i manually edit the html file to fix it).

I dont have this problem with any other elements in modules except sometimes with display templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the display template didn't update costed me a long time...this will save you some hours:

Inside the display template I included a JavaScript .js
Inside the same display template I also had a JavaScript function with the same name

I guess it was skipped and an older version was put back in place during activation.

solved

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: i am the author and this WAS / IS the solution:

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and till now I found only a workaround and a solution.

Workaround: 
If you close and reopen Visual Studio magically the display template.

Solution:
Check out this page: [page](http://mohitvash.wordpress.com/2014/06/24/display-template-deployment-in-sharepoint-2013/)